# Submit form as soon as it is created in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-hooks

I have a form with id `redirectForm` which I need to auto-submit as soon as it is created in the DOM. I am using React Hooks. My current code doesn't work.

```js
const Pay = () => {
  const [payToken, setPayToken] = useState('');
  const generatePaymentToken = () => {
        fetch('https://somepostdomain.com/v1/GenerateChecksum', {
            method: 'post',
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                orderId: '1',
                orderAmount: amt,
            })
        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                setPayToken(res.checksumValue);
            })
    };

  useEffect(() => {
    const form = document.getElementById('redirectForm');//Not working
    //console.log("form", form);
  }, []);

  return (
    <button onClick={generatePaymentToken}>Pay</button>
    {payToken !== '' ? (
    <>
      <form
        id="redirectForm"
        method="post"
        action="https://test.somedomain.com/checkout/post/submit"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="appId" value="<YOUR_APPID_HERE>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="order00001" />
        <input type="hidden" name="signature" value={payToken} />
      </form>
      {document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit()}//This throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null
    </>
   ) : (
    <></>
   )}
   <></>
  );
};
```

submit() throws `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submit' of null`

How do I make sure that the form is created before submit() is called?

Comment: you can use `useEffect` hook i.e. `useEffect(() => {
     document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
  }, []); ` it works like `componentDidMount` and you can access the form element

Comment: @an0nym0us I have tried it, throws the same error.

Comment: can you post the code in which you have tried using it

Comment: @an0nym0us added

Comment: i have added the answer. Remove  this code `{document.getElementById('redirectForm').submit()}` from `return` statement. This why you are getting the error.

Comment: @an0nym0us @ kooskoos I just realized error could be due to the "payToken" being fetched after the user clicks the "Pay" button. The form is created after the "payToken" is fetched and passed to the form. Pardon me for not mentioning it before.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access DOM elements inside `return` statement. In class based component, we use `componentDidMount` method to access the DOM elements. And in functional component, you can use `Effect` hook.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Pay = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const form = document.getElementById("redirectForm");
    console.log("form", form);
    // document.getElementById("redirectForm").submit();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <form
        id="redirectForm"
        method="post"
        action="https://test.somedomain.com/checkout/post/submit"
      >
        <input type="hidden" name="appId" value="<YOUR_APPID_HERE>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="orderId" value="order00001" />
      </form>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-vaughan-sb8hr

It works as expected

Comment: I have made few changes to the code. Pardon for not mentioning it earlier.